# Kivy - How to Size Embedded Anchor Layouts?

Tags: python-3.x, layout, kivy, kivy-language, sizing

I would like to build the following simple design in a .kv file.

[image: design]

It is made of 3 parts :

- One top-left Anchor Layout which is made up of a Grid Layout of 3 columns. I want its width to be equal to 20% of the window's with and its height to be equal to 75% of the window's height.
- One top-right Anchor Layout which is made up of a vertically-oriented Box Layout. I want its width to be equal to 80% of the window's with and its height to be equal to 75% of the window's height.
- One bottom-left Anchor Layout which is empty for the moment. I want its height to be 25% of the window's height.

These three parts are themselves included in an AnchorLayout.

I tried to translate this design into a .kv file as follows.

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<Example>:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        anchor_y: "top"
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.75)

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        anchor_y: "top"
        size_hint: (0.8, 0.75)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: "HELLO..."
            Label:
                text: "WORLD..."

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        size_hint: (1, 0.25)

        Label:
            text: "FOOTER"
```

In case it matters, here is the code of my .py file as well.

```
# Importing Kivy
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")

# Importing kivy libraries
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


# Importing external libraries


# Import kv files
Builder.load_file("example.kv")


# Root widget of the application
class Example(AnchorLayout):
    pass


# Application class
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
        return Example()

# Launch the application
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

The output does not look as I expected as shown on the picture below :

[image: screenshot2]

I don't get it. Because the AnchorLayout is a subclass of the Widget class and is itself included within a Layout, its size_hint property should enable me to define its size.

What am I missing here ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `anchor_x` and `anchor_y` properties of the `AnchorLayout` affect the children of the `AnchorLayout`, so your `Example` layout is trying to put all its children close to the center.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is perfectly logical!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem - design centered

The design is placed in the center.

## Root Cause

The root is an [AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html) with value `'center'` for both `anchor_x` and `anchor_y`. Therefore, all its children (the `AnchorLayout`s) are placed in respect to the root.

Below is a view of your design in different colours for visualization.

[image: Design - canvas painted]

### [AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html)

The [AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html#kivy.uix.anchorlayout.AnchorLayout) aligns its children to a border (top, bottom, left, right) or center.

## Solution

There are three possible solutions to your design. The preference is method 1.

### Method 1 - No `AnchorLayout`s

This method replace all `AnchorLayout`s with `BoxLayout`s. It use one less `AnchorLayout` widget which makes the app more resource efficient i.e. use less memory and the app is smaller.

#### Snippets - Method 1

```
<Example>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        ...
        GridLayout:    # left box
            ...
        BoxLayout:    # right box
            ...
    BoxLayout:    # footer
        ...
```

### Method 2 - `BoxLayout` as root

This method replace the root widget with `BoxLayout` and realign the left box.

#### Snippets - Method 2

```
<Example>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    AnchorLayout:
        ...
        GridLayout:    # left box
            ...
        AnchorLayout:    # right box
            ...
    AnchorLayout:    # footer
        ...
```

### Method 3

This method add a `BoxLayout` as a child of the root, and the rest of the `AnchorLayout` as children of the `BoxLayout`.

#### Snippets - Method 3

```
<Example>:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        AnchorLayout:
            ...
            GridLayout:    # left box
                ...
            AnchorLayout:    # right box
                ...
        AnchorLayout:    # footer
            ...
```

## Example

### Method 1 - No `AnchorLayout`s

#### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.75

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 0.2, 1

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            cols: 3
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 40

            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"            

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            Label:
                text: "HELLO..."
            Label:
                text: "WORLD..."


    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.25

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        Label:
            text: "FOOTER"

"""))
```

#### Output: Method 1 - No `AnchorLayout`s

[image: Output: Method 1 - No <code>AnchorLayout</code>s]

### Method 2 - `BoxLayout` as root

#### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.75
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 0.2, 1

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            cols: 3
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 40

            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"            

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'top'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.8, 1

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                Label:
                    text: "HELLO..."
                Label:
                    text: "WORLD..."


    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        Label:
            text: "FOOTER"

"""))
```

#### Output: Method 2 - `BoxLayout` as root

[image: Output: Method 2 - <code>BoxLayout</code> as root]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this really exhaustive answer which helps a lot to understand how layouts work in Kivy. You're right, Anchor Layouts are in fact not needed to yield the targeted design.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Example` class to extend `FloatLayout` instead of `AnchorLayout` allows more control of its children. With that change to `Example`, here is a `kv` that looks more like what you want:

```
<Example>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.75)
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'top':1}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"
            Button:
                text: "X"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "top"
        size_hint: (0.8, 0.75)
        pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':1}

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: "HELLO..."
            Label:
                text: "WORLD..."

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        size_hint: (1, 0.25)
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}

        Label:
            text: "FOOTER"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed the root anchor layout was centering all the child anchor layouts!